# Meu ListView não aparece conteúdo

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-forms

Não aparece o texto do Label que está no `ListView`, já cheguei a utilizar o `StackLayout` e nada, o que poderia ser?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O ListView é um componente para apresentar lista de dados na tela. Para isso você deve definir uma fonte de dados para popular o ListView como uma lista(List), vetor(Array) ou qualquer IEnumerable.

No seu caso você não está passando nenhuma fonte de dados para seu ListView apresentar.

Documentação do ListView: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/